# Postman request to PHP using POST

Tags: php, post, request, postman

This is my code:

```php
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["test"]))
        echo $_POST["test"];
    if(isset($_GET["test"]))
        echo $_GET["test"];
?>
```

My question is: **why POST request doesn't work?**

I have tried different parameters in the body and the header and nothing works.

GET request in Postman works:
[image: GET request Postman]

POST request in Postman fails:
[image: POST request Postman]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
<?php 
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  echo $name;
?>
```

Comment: I used your same code and the same request in the postman, this was the answer

<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: name in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\index.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />

Comment: can you share your postman request page image and php code here

Comment: this is the code
<?php 
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  echo $name;
?> 
your same code.
and the POST request is exactly the same as your request

Comment: another interesting fact. sending the data from a form works perfectly
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name" value="HELLO">
<input type="submit">
</form>

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to set the headers as **"Content-Type"-"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"** and **disable** *"Content-Type"-"application/json".*

After that in the body tab select **"x-www-form-urlencoded" field** *not the "raw" field* and enter the values you need to post as the post request.

Don't forget to change the **request type to POST**.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the header tab, set "Content-Type"-"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
2. In the body tab, choose form-data
3. Enter your key/value pairs. These represent the name parameter in your PHP or HTML form and their expected values
4. Change request type to POST and enter the url of the script that will process the form. This is the full url of the action parameter in your form

Answer (score 0):

Your request might be redirected:

> - All of your requests are sent as GET requests, no matter which HTTP request method you select.
> - The original HTTP request method you selected is not preserved when there is a redirect between HTTP and HTTPS."

https://support.postman.com/hc/en-us/articles/211913929-My-request-is-redirected-to-a-GET-request